# Using a fixture as several parameters in pytest.mark.parametrize

Tags: python, pytest

I want to to pass a fixture that represents several parameters to pytest.mark.parametrize, e.g:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def get_test_data():
    return [("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3)]
    
@pytest.mark.parametrize("letter, number", get_test_data)
def test_output(letter, number): 
    assert True
```

But all I'm getting is:
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

I tried using lazyfixture and getfixturevalue, nothing worked.
Help will be appreciated.

EDIT:
Please note my test data (i.e. get_test_data's return value) is not known to me before running the test, it is obtained on the fly (by looking at other files when the fixture gets called).

Answer (score 0):

Use `pytest.fixture` request and params, like this:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(
    scope="session",
    name="letter_number_test_data",
    params=[("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3)],
)
def _letter_number_test_data(request):
    return request.param


def test_output(letter_number_test_data):
    letter, number = letter_number_test_data
    assert ... # here goes whatever assert you need
```

You can read more about it here:
https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytest-fixture

Comment: Thanks, this is close to what I'm looking for, however those params aren't known to me before I run the script.
For simplicity, let's say the fixture's operation is opening a txt file which it parses into params.
(In this example, the txt file could have the following content:
a 1, b 2, c 3)

Comment: Sorry, but lost me there completely. I'm not sure what's your goal anymore. Are you changing implementation between test runs? If not you should have a defined set of parameters I guess (for which your feature should work / should not work). What's the added value of reading those from a file? Maybe someone else can help you then.

Comment: In my real test I don't read them from a txt file, but I am getting that data on the fly (by looking through a bunch of files and saving their paths). The txt file is an example for a way to simulate getting data on the fly, rather than it being directly hard-coded in the test.